# The 'return' keyword is not working correctly in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, return-value

I am using this piece of function to check if a file exists. If the file exists then I am changing its name:

```
function checkFileExist($fileName, $z, $ext, $folderWIthFileName){
    $tmpNam = "";
    if (file_exists($fileName . "_" . $z . "." . $ext)) {
        $z = $z + 1;
        checkFileExist($fileName, $z, $ext, $folderWIthFileName);
    }
    else {
        $tmpNam = $fileName . "_" . $z;
        echo "in else <br> " . $fileName . "_" . $z . "<br>";
    }
    return $tmpNam;
}
```

And calling this function like

```
$definename = checkFileExist($folderWIthFileName . "/" . $InvId, $z, $ext, $folderWIthFileName);
echo "new name is " . $definename;
```

But this gives me output like this:

```
in else
444_2015-10-27/444_3
new name is
```

You can see return is not working correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're missing a return before your recursive call to checkFileExist, or maybe you want to assign the value to $tmpNam and have it return at the end of the function.

Comment: I don't want to return anything when i am calling function recursively. There is no use of return in recursive function.

Comment: as per @zxcmehran answer, its working fine. yes may be i am wrong. But whats the use of return when i am calling function inside function?

Comment: Either the file doesn't exist and you get the filename right away (second return statement), or the file does exist and you get the result of the recursive call - but you have to return it or you never get it!

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `return checkFileExist($fileName, $z, $ext, $folderWIthFileName);` in the first block to return back a value from the recursively made calls. Use this clean version:

```
function checkFileExist($fileName, $z, $ext, $folderWIthFileName) {
    if (file_exists($fileName . "_" . $z . "." . $ext)) {
        return checkFileExist($fileName, $z+1, $ext, $folderWIthFileName);
    }
    return $fileName . "_" . $z;
}
```

Comment: Don't really need `$z = $z + 1;`, can just call the function again with `$z + 1` as the parameter.